# checkmk custom check and graph

Tags: bash, monitoring, nagios

I'd like to add some custom check and add a graph. Basically it's a bash script that write 1 value to a file every minute. I'd like this value to be presented in a graph. I can see this check under services but can't create a graph for it.

I've tried to edit: /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local/mycustomscript
so it's content is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "1 myservice2 count1=42|count2=21;23;27|count3=73 OK - This is my custom output"
```